# Display by date not by workweek MYSQL C#

Tags: c#, mysql, database, mysql-workbench

Can anyone help me display my code by date like that not by yearweek
My data is schedule per day and i want to summarize it by week like in table

```
"SELECT EmployeeName,AssignedArea,SectionName,TimeSchedule,YEARWEEK(ScheduleFrom) as ScheduleFrom 
from tblschedule 
WHERE ScheduleFrom BETWEEN '" + clsSQLcon.DateFrom1+"' AND '"+clsSQLcon.DateTo1+"'
```

[[1]: Here is the sample of my output but i want it by date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENI30.png)

| Employeenames | 2021-03-01 | 2021-03-08 | 2021-03-15 | 2021-03-22 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Candare | time& section for the week | time& section for the week | time& section for the week | time& section for the week |
| Mendoza | time& section for the week | time& section for the week | time& section for the week | time& section for the week |
| Jocson | time& section for the week | time& section for the week | time& section for the week | time& section for the week |

Comment: Fix the SQL injection bug first, by using a parameterized query. There's *no* good reason to construct queries by concatenating user input

Comment: i dunno how.. i just want the reports by days summarize by week but not the it summarized by yearweek but its not a date i need date not yearweek im stressed HAHAHAHA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't comment due to not having at least 50 reputation; so I'm not able to ask clarifying questions.

Would using [STR_TO_DATE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_str_to_date.asp) solve your problem?

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEARWEEK("2021-03-10"), ' Wednesday'), '%X%V %W');
>> 2021-03-10
```

Note: You need to supply the day of the week as the 2nd parameter of STR_TO_DATE.
You can form this second parameter by concatenating an empty space and DAYNAME(date).

[Here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/81H1PYDf5zjrsNF6FM4viS/4) is a fiddle demonstrating this.

Comment: i already try this sir but it still not giving me te right report

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEARWEEK((ScheduleFrom)),' Monday'), '%X%V %W') as ScheduleFrom from tblschedule
```

thanks for the help